# How to Move Rows to the Right in Bootsrap 5?

Tags: html

I want to move 2 rows at the right of the page so everything will be in right order, 2 rows on the left, button in the middle and 2 rows at the right! I will post an image and my source code!

[Project Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWMle.jpg)

My source code using bootsrap 5:

```
function Converter () {
  return (
    <div className="card card-body p-3 mb-2 bg-light text-dark">
      <h1>Currency Converter</h1>
        <form>
          <div className="d-flex">
          <div className="form-row col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div className="form-group col-md-8">
              <label><strong>Currency I Have:</strong></label>
              <select className="form-select" type="text" >
                <option value="1" selected >USD</option>
                <option value="2">EUR</option>
                <option value="3">GBP</option>
                <option value="3">CAD</option>
                <option value="3">AUD</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group col-md-8">
              <label><strong>Amount:</strong></label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control"/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="form-row col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div className="form-group col-md-8">
              <label><strong>Currency I Want:</strong></label>
              <select className="form-select" type="text" >
                <option value="1" selected >EUR</option>
                <option value="2">USA</option>
                <option value="3">GBP</option>
                <option value="3">CAD</option>
                <option value="3">AUD</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group col-md-8">
              <label><strong>Amount:</strong></label>
              <input type="number" className="form-control"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Convert</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Is it what you want or what you currently have on the image ?

Comment: The image displays what I currently have! I want to move the 2 rows on the right at the very end with the button in the middle!

Comment: take a look at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/columns/#horizontal-alignment

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-5">
  <div class="row">
       code for first drop downs
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">

</div>
<div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="row">
       code for Second list of drop downs
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Nazeer Shaik! Will try it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this and fill your code snippets:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-evenly">
            <div class="col-md-5 text-start">
                <!-- First drop down -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
                <!-- Button -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 text-end">
                <!-- Second drop down -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Ojas Mahajan!